# value error exception when try to generate tokens to access google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

When i am executing the below python code to read my data from google sheet this is the first method to call to generate tokens but i am getting the **value error exception** when this line of code executed.

```
       InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)




    def gsheet_api_check(SCOPES):
      creds = None
     if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
          creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
      if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
      else:
       flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)

       creds = flow.run_local_server()
   

   with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
       pickle.dump(creds, token)
   return creds
```

-- calling the above function

```
  SCOPES = 
 ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
  creds = gsheet_api_check(SCOPES)
```

what will be the issue i also downloaded the credentials.json file generated using google project and copied the file in the project path.

i am not able to find the issue please do let me know what is the issues here in the above code.